# Prove at least one of $\pi+e$, $\pi e$ is transcendental.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I understand to prove at least one of them irrational you would compose a function by which $\pi$ and $e$ are roots $((x-\pi)(x-e))$, and show that at least one coefficient cannot be rational because $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental.

From here I developed $3$ cases;

$1)$ $(\pi+e)$ is rational and $(\pi e)$ is irrational or

$2)$ $(\pi+e)$ is irrational and $(\pi e)$ is rational or

$3)$ $(\pi+e)$ is irrational and $(\pi e)$ is irrational

I compose a new function, $(x-(\pi+e))(x-(\pi e))$, which produces $x^2+(\pi+e+\pi e)x+(\pi+e)(\pi e)$

For cases $1$ and $2$, they are transcendental, but I am unsure of how to show it for case $3.$

Comment: Are you kidding...didn't even check Wikipedia (-1)

Comment: At the onset please start using MathJax so your questions become more readable. Secondly have you done some reading on transcendental nature ?

Comment: For those unaware, this is a well-known open question (if one of them in particular is transcendental). The proof at least one of them is transcendental is more-or-less given in the question.

Comment: I have. From what I've read, if a number is transcendental, a polynomial cannot be composed with rational coefficients where the number is one of the roots. As such, I have shown that they are both irrational, but am unsure of how to show $\pi+e$ or $\pi e$ are transcendental

Comment: @Zach466920 I thought i read that "We're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about math." in the overview of math's exchange. So it is is pointless to down vote a question on the basis that the answer lie somewhere else other than here. here is the link see it, http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @ritwiksinha Uhm...you haven't checked the myriad of similar questions on this site. A good rule of thumb is that if its on Wikipedia its been asked here...

Comment: @Zach466920 That's sounds valid. I didn't know that thumb rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is that if $\alpha$ satisfies a polynomial $p(x)$ with *algebraic* coefficients (not just rational coefficients), then $\alpha$ must be algebraic.  This can be proven with some linear algebra: let $K$ be the field generated by the coefficients of $p$.  Since the coefficients are algebraic, $K$ has finite dimension over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Since the vector space formed by the powers of $\alpha$ is finite-dimensional over $K$, it is also finite-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$.  That is, some linear combination of the powers of $\alpha$ with rational coefficients vanishes, so $\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial with rational coefficients.

So now if $\pi e$ and $\pi+e$ were both algebraic, then the polynomial $p(x)=(x-\pi)(x-e)$ would have algebraic coefficients.  This implies that its roots ($\pi$ and $e$) would be algebraic, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 12):

If $\pi+e$ and $\pi e$ were both algebraic, then $(\pi+e)^2-4\pi e$ would be algebraic, and thefore $\pi-e$ would be algebraic. But then $\frac{1}{2}((\pi+e)-(\pi-e))$ would be algebraic, that is, $e$ would be algebraic, which is not the case.